# Verify Product available in shopping cart then remove using remove link a using selenium Java . Here number of product is unknown

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, conditional-statements, radix

selenium script in java to check product available in shopping cart , if available then remove using remove link.

```
for(int i = result; i >= 0;  i--) {

   boolean str = "Product available with remove link";

   if(str) {
      // Click on remove link till remove link there to remove all product 
   }  
   else {
      // Verify no product present Text 
   }
}
```

Problem here Loop is running only once and removing only one product.
Every product have associated remove link. We don't know the number of product listed in shopping cart. So we have to remove all of them. If not available then show message product not listed.

Comment: Your code won't compile. `str` is declared as a `boolean` but you are assigning a string to it. Edit your question and post some relevant HTML. Where is your code that actually attempts this? You've posted barely a skeleton of what might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method inside the `if`.

```
public void removeProducts() {
    List<WebElement> removeProductBtnList = driver.findElements(locator);
    for (WebElement removeProductBtn : removeProductBtnList ) { 
        driver.findElement(locator).click();
        //removeProductBtn.click();  you can also use this line instead of the above, 
        //but it will probably return a StaleElementReferenceException after the first click.
    }
}
```

this method does nothing if there are no removeButtons on the shopping cart.